# Keyboard extension input auto enter

Tags: ios, swift, enter, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm developing a keyboard extension to have it custom for my distinct host app. The keyboard is connected with hardware barcode scanner.

I have problem to auto 'send' the form when the barcode read. So, if I have other string (barcode) combine with the (`"\r"`), this will not trigger the auto send.

```
func performBarcodeScan(barcode: String, scanner: String) {
        textDocumentProxy.insertText(barcode+"\r")
}
```

But, I tried with this situation where I already type some string input in the field and have only (`"\r"`) as below, that will work:

```
func performBarcodeScan(barcode: String, scanner: String) {
        textDocumentProxy.insertText("\r")
}
```

Having the `insertText` twice to separate the string also does not work.

Having dummy changes on input view as below will sometimes make it work, sometimes not:

```
barcode = barcode + "1"
textDocumentProxy.insertText(barcode)
textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward(times: 1)
textDocumentProxy.insertText("\r")
```

How can I solve this?